# Centrar imagenes con bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Tengo tres imagenes y lo que deseo es centrarlas y que haya espacio entre ellas.

Estoy utilizando bootstrap y no lo he podido conseguir, alguien tiene idea de como hacerlo?Dejo una captura de las imagenes[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí] y el codigo para que se entienda mas

```html
<section id="estadisticas" class="ocultar_r">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-sm-4 text-center">
            <h2 class="mb-4">ESTADÍSTICAS DE LRFA</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Praesentium, esse magnam adipisci tenetur quos eaque quia quidem molestias excepturi </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row justify-content-around" id="">
        <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
            <div id="padre">
                <img id="content_div_one_photo" class="rounded " src="https://lorempixel.com/160/110/cats/1/">
                
            </div>
            <div id="padre">
                <img id="content_div_one_photo" class="rounded " src="https://lorempixel.com/160/110/cats/1/">
                
            </div>
            <div id="padre">
                <img id="content_div_one_photo" class="rounded " src="https://lorempixel.com/160/110/cats/1/">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

estas poniendo todas las imágenes dentro de un solo contenedor (col-sm-12), pero para que funcione el "justify-content-around" debes poner cada imagen en un contenedor diferente. Yo usé "col" pero puedes usar el que te acomode

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<section id="estadisticas" class="ocultar_r">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-sm-4 text-center">
                <h2 class="mb-4">ESTADÍSTICAS DE LRFA</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Praesentium, esse magnam adipisci tenetur quos eaque quia quidem molestias excepturi </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="row justify-content-around" id="">
            <div class="col text-center">
              <img id="content_div_one_photo" class="rounded " src="https://lorempixel.com/160/110/cats/1/">
            </div>
              <div class="col text-center">
                      <img id="content_div_one_photo" class="rounded " src="https://lorempixel.com/160/110/cats/1/">
              </div>
              <div class="col text-center">
                      <img id="content_div_one_photo" class="rounded " src="https://lorempixel.com/160/110/cats/1/">
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        
    </section>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias me sirvio eres un crack.Si quisiera ponerle textos dentro de las imagenes tienes idea como se puede hacer?

Comment: te puedes guiar por este vínculo. Si no puedes hacerlo te ayudo https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_image_text